# How do I get accented Spanish with "Spanish (no dead keys)"?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I have been using the default Spanish keyboard layout for some time and it works well. It uses a dead key (the quote key) to get accented vowels. I press ' followed by e, for example, and get é. The problem is that this no longer works with FluentU. So I thought I'd try "Spanish (no dead keys)". But I can't figure out how to use it. With this setup, what exactly do I have to do to get an accented character? This is Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: So you wanna eat the cake and have it too? ;) Maybe you want to check out the _Compose key_ and _Code points_ sections at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did look at those. However, the compose key sequences sound like another way to get a single character via a sequence of keypresses. What I want is a single keypress (perhaps with some sort of shifting) to get the single accented character.